# Can I implement a custom security implementation in Hazelcast Opensource?

Tags: security, open-source, hazelcast

Question is simple: can I implement a concept of security policies or encryption of traffic *without* having to go with the enterprise license?  I ask because I remember this being possible in the earlier versions of hazelcast of 2-3 years ago.  I'm not looking for an implementation, just the hooks to roll my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fair to say not easily as this is one of the key features of Enterprise edition that keeps Hazelcast in business. All of the documented entry points seem to be only available with the JAAS based enterprise option.

Comments like the one in this thread

```
  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8370
```

Indicate that developers could use some of the low level interfaces such as NodeExtension, but I've never seen an implementation.

The easiest solution seems to be to just wrap the whole deployment in VPN sessions.